# Почему в методе всегда возвращает 0 ? Код библиотеки и приложения в сообщении

Tags: c#, wpf, классы, dll, методы

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
 
namespace Variant2
{
    public class Room
    {
        double length;
        double width;
 
        public double Length
        {
            get { return length; }
            set { length = value; }
        }
        public double Width
        {
            get { return width; }
            set { width = value; }
 
        }
        public double square()
        {
            return length * width;
        }
        public double AreaPerson(int n)
        {
            return square() / n;
        }
 
 
    }
    public class Office : Room
    {
        double rozetok;
 
        public double Rozetok
        {
            get { return rozetok; }
            set { rozetok = value; }
        }
        public double Places(double s)
        {
            if (rozetok >= 2 && square() > s)
            {
                return square() / rozetok;
 
            }
            else
            {
                return 0;
            }
 
 
 
        }
 
    }
}
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Variant2;
 
namespace WpfApp31
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Логика взаимодействия для MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        Room room1 = new Room();
        Office office = new Office();
 
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        
 
        private void BT_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            room1.Length = Convert.ToDouble(TB1.Text);
            room1.Width = Convert.ToDouble(TB2.Text);
            office.Rozetok = Convert.ToDouble(TB3.Text);
            double norm = Convert.ToDouble(TB4.Text);
            Label1.Content = office.Places(norm);
 
 
 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А в каком именно методе возвращает 0?

Comment: public double Places(double s)

Answer (score 1):

Рассмотрим класс `MainWindow`. Вы создали 2 приватных поля и инициализировали их:

```
Room room1    = new Room();
Office office = new Office();
```

При нажатии на кнопку, вы присваиваете введённые значения длины и ширины свойствам `Length` и `Width` поля `room1`:

```
room1.Length = Convert.ToDouble(TB1.Text);
room1.Width  = Convert.ToDouble(TB2.Text);
```

`office.Length` же и `office.Width` остались со значениями по умолчанию `0d`!
После этого вы присваиваете введённое значение (количества розеток?) свойству `Rozetok` поля `office`:

```
office.Rozetok = Convert.ToDouble(TB3.Text);
```

Последнее действие - вызов метода `office.Place(norm)`, которое у вас

> всегда возвращает 0

Рассмотри класс `Office`. Как видно из вашего кода

```
public double Places(double s)
{
   if (rozetok >= 2 && square() > s)
       return square() / rozetok;
   else
       return 0;
}
```

метод `Places(double s)` возвращает `0d` в двух случаях:

1. если **не** выполнится условие `rozetok >= 2 && square() > s`
2. если `square()` вернёт `0d` (деление нуля на число)

Давайте вычислим `office.square()`. Вот его код:

```
public double square()
{
    return length * width;
}
```

Так как `office.Length` и `office.Width` мы нигде не присваивали, `office.square()` = `0d * 0d` = `0d`. Следовательно, вызов `office.Places(norm)` вернёт `0d` вне зависимости от аргумента.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, вы создавали экземпляр класса Office `var office = new Office();`. Таким образом, в `Rozetor` у вас не было ничего и возвращал он при обращении дефолтное значение для double (0). Нужно добавить конструктор класса (`public Office(...)`). Также, ваш код можно сократить, избавившись от лишнего поля и сократив метод.

```
public class Office : Room
{
    public double Rozetor { get; private set; }

    public Office(double rozetor)
    {
        Rozetor = rozetor;
    }

    public double Places(double s) =>
        rozetok >= 2 && square() > s
           ? square() / rozetok
           : 0;
}
```